# Ternary In Onclick

Tags: javascript, razor

I am working in .Net Core 2.1 and am trying to do a ternary operator in an onclick event, like so:

`<a class="btn archiveButton" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#archivePerson"  onclick="@(dept.ManagerFlag == true ? "ArchiveManager(@dept.EmployeeId);" : "ArchiveEmployee(@dept.EmployeeId);")">`

ArchiveEmployee(@dept.EmployeeId) works when condition is met but when condition is met for ArchiveManager, I get error: `Uncaught SyntaxError: Invalid or unexpected token`.

Am I doing something incorrectly?

Answer (score 0):

I think the JavaScript need information about the parameter `@dept.EmployeeId` and to resolve the problem you need to pass this parameter in quotes

```
<a class="btn archiveButton" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#archivePerson" 
 onclick="@(dept.ManagerFlag == true ? "ArchiveManager
 ('@dept.EmployeeId');" : "ArchiveEmployee('@dept.EmployeeId');")">
```

Comment: unfortunately that did not work. When ManagerFlag == False i see - in Google inspect - dept.EmployeeId = 3213213 but when ManagerFlag == true it is still dept.EmployeeId